# How to make search in select box using React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, multi-select

I am making a select box with the help of [Antd design](https://3x.ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-multiple).

**Current scenario**:

-> I am making two select box here, in which one select has static data and another from api.

**Issue**:

-> While I type keyword to select options, static one works but the dynamic options (data from api) **doesn't works** and display the No data text.

**Expectation**:

Both the static and dynamic select box needs to display the options as per the search keyword in the select box.

Code: (Options as static)

```
  <Select mode="multiple" style={{ width: 120 }}>
    <Select.Option value="jack">Jack</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="lucy">Lucy</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="disabled" disabled>
      Disabled
    </Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Select.Option>
  </Select>
```

[image]

Code: (Options from api)

```
  <Select mode="multiple" style={{ width: 120 }}>
    {data.map(({ label, value, text }) =>
      label ? (
        <Select.Option value={value || ""} key={label}>
          {text}
        </Select.Option>
      ) : null
    )}
  </Select>
```

[image]

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit antd-select-clear (forked)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up the label and value values. The `label` is the name value that you are typing in and trying to match.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const userData = data.map((item) => ({
        label: item.login, // <-- input values you are matching
        value: item.id
      }));
      setData(userData);
    });
}, []);

...

<Select mode="multiple" style={{ width: 120 }}>
  {data.map(({ label, value, text }) => (
    <Select.Option value={label} key={value}> // <-- label is option value
      {label}
    </Select.Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-search-in-select-box-using-react-js]

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. May I know the reason it gives this error in typescript? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oVoD.png

Comment: @HelloWorld Not sure. All the response data had values with `login` and `id` values that are used for the `label` and `value` properties, so I removed the guard check you had in your code on `label`. Is this propType/Typescript warning on this `Select.Option` component? Does the warning go away if you filter `data` first? Something like `data.filter(({ label }) => label).map(item => ......)`?

Comment: Yes bro, It is from `Select.Option` component. Sorry for missing out typescript usage in the question.

Comment: No bro, still the error comes https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tIq7.png . Even after using filter and map chain.

Comment: @HelloWorld Do you have a sandbox for this code but in Typescript? Maybe it's how you've declared the `data` state.

Comment: Give me few mins bro, will create it and share here.

Comment: I have created example here https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-file-upload-validation-in-reactjs-forked-ubucyb but unfortunately unable to reproduce the issue. I will debug in my app bro.

Comment: But if I need to get the selected id, the how can I get bro? Even if I search for the user, it is a text but once after the selection, I need to get the id selected to pass down to Backend api.

Comment: @HelloWorld It looks like there's an `onChange` handler that receives the selected values, you could cross-reference these with the data to get the associated id values. https://3x.ant.design/components/select/#Select-props

Answer (score 1):

It works when value is as same as option text. Probably antd's peculiarity

```
  <Select mode="multiple" style={{ width: 120 }}>
    {data.map(({ label, value, text }) =>
      label ? (
        <Select.Option value={label} key={label}>
          {text}
        </Select.Option>
      ) : null
    )}
  </Select>
```